# Visual Studio Code not working with Zsh on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, visual-studio-code, oh-my-zsh

If i try to use VS Code with zsh, it says "The terminal process command '/usr/bin/zsh' failed to launch (exit code: 1)".

First I tried to set '"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/zsh"' in the settings, error.
Next I tried to '"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": ""' the same error.
After that I tried try one and two in combination with setting '"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": ["-l"]'

I am using Manjaro with Z Shell and Oh-My-Zsh.

Thank you

Comment: May be you typed wrong path. The actual path is `/usr/bin/zsh` and your provided warning shows `/bin/zsh`.

Comment: I am having the same issue (also Manjaro Gnome with zsh and oh-my-zsh, although for me it's *exit code: -3*) `"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/usr/bin/zsh"` doesn't solve the issue

Comment: I think the issue might be connected to having setting files e.g. `.zshrc`, `.profile` etc. open in vscode

Answer (score 1):

I solved it one way. You could have installed VS Code through Flatpak. Try installing "Code - OSS (code)", which is an "Official Repositories (community)" version.

When I had installed the Flatpak version, I already had received a warning saying the software might not be well integrated to the system, because it was a Flatpak version. I always kept in mind, remembered that warning, and even had a guess my terminal wasn't working due to that. Because the name was different (Code - OSS (code)) and the logo too, I had a feeling it was an inferior, different "copycat" version. But I see it's just the same, and the terminal works "out of the box". I just had to setup the fonts, so symbols would show up at the terminal prompt. I can explain how to do that if you have that issue too, as it was hard to find a solution sugestion that worked.

Hope that solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have the Flatpak version. If it is the case you can try to use named as `bash` but with `zsh` instead:

```json
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
      "bash": {
        "path": "/usr/bin/flatpak-spawn",
        "overrideName": true,
        "args": ["--host", "--env=TERM=xterm-256color", "zsh"]
      }
    },
```